# Is it okay to use legacy Firebase Push after March 31, 2021?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

It seems that binary push notifications aren't available from March 31, 2021, but is it okay to use legacy Firebase Push?

■Apple Developper news
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b